Smart Contracts data for a thesis on commodity trading
I am considering writing my master's thesis in finance on smart contracts and commodity trading. I would like to conduct an analysis on the trading behavior of smart contracts as opposed to traditional stock exchanges. For example, I would like to compare trading volumes for smart contracts facilitating the trade of oil futures to trading data from CME on these instruments.
However, I struggle to find reliable trading data on embedded smart contracts. Are there just none?
Do you have any other suggestions on what kind of empirical comparative analysis I could conduct?
Kind regards

Finding data on smart contract trading volume, especially for commodities like oil futures, is challenging. Traditional market data sources don't capture activity on Decentralized Exchanges (DEXes) where these tokens trade.
Here's what you can explore:

Blockchain explorers
On-chain data analysis tools


Yeah I tried these but to no avail. It is crazy. On one hand, there have been papers calling for implementation for nearly a decade, on the other hand, the few contracts that were "tested" have been inactive for about two years, if at all. I think the main issue is that even testing is quite expensive with the "gas" required to facilitate trades. Too bad I can't find something good for my the empiric part of my thesis

@gerscorpion correct.

@gerscorpion kindly if you find this answer helpful you can accept it.
